# How do I read the file from the top using cat command?

Tags: bash, unix, file-io, terminal, cat

I have a file **constants.php** and when I run this command  `cat constants.php` it always shows me, the content of the file from the bottom. But **I want to see the content from the top of the files**, because my file has more then 500 lines of code.

I tried `head -1 constants.php` but it will show only first line, which is not useful, I need to see all the content from the Top.

Comment: what is your definition of "TOP". Head can be used to read from TOP with specifying how many lines etc

Comment: `cat` reads from top to bottom like anything else. There's no paging, though, the top part of the file will scroll off-screen, leaving only the bottom of the list on screen.

Comment: `cat` command always shows contents from starting (from 1st line on-wards only), not sure how you are seeing different behavior.

Comment: You want to use a pager like `less` or `more`. Voting to close, as this is not a programming question.

Comment: @chepner try with the file which has more then 100 lines of code and check.

Comment: Reread my comment. The top however-may lines are read, but they scroll off the top of the screen. `cat` is not reading from the bottom of the file.

Comment: If you don't believe me, run `cat some_file | head -10` (which, yes, is equivalent to `head -10 file`). You will get the first 10 lines of the file, not 10 lines from the bottom.

Comment: whenever I typed `cat constants.php` it shows all the content, but cursor is on the bottom, so I have to scroll up, to see the content of the first line.

Comment: In general, if you terminal size is `n` rows, then `head -n $((n-1))` will fill your screen with the top of the file. (Subtracting one, because your shell will push the output up one line to make room for a new prompt.)

Comment: Tried this `head -n $((n-200)) constants.php` and it's showing  first 55 lines from the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204354/discussion-between-yogi-ghorecha-and-chepner).

Comment: Why don't you try more filename instead of cat if you want a page pause from top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a head command for that.

Details here:
https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/view-the-beginning-of-text-files-with-head/